# How to request https by ip address?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, https

How to make a https request by ip address?, by example, with cloudflare:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://104.18.5.125/', verify=False, headers={ 'host': 'example.com' })
...
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='104.18.5.125', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')])")))
```

But when make the request using the original hostname works fine.

```py
>>> requests.get('https://example.com/', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

When try access from Mozilla Firefox says: `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`.

Need test remote https servers for virtual host checking, but can not made the request using the ip address. How to disable warnings from python3 code and made the request?

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates usually include the domain name for the website but not the IP, this means when you tried making a request using HTTPS, since there was no available certificate for the IP it resulted in an handshake failure.

To fix this you need to either stop using HTTPS or get an SSL certificate for the IP address.

Comment: If I don't have the hostname associated with the certificate, can't I make any http request?

Comment: I have a domain with 3 associated IP addresses and I need to check that each IP responds to the same content of the virtual host, is there a way to tell requests to use a specific domain but connecting to an IP address?

Comment: You can make an `HTTP` request but not an `HTTPS` request

Comment: Are there any providers that assign certificate for ip address rather than domain name?